# Restart network interface - Angstrom linux

Tags: networking, angstrom

I have an embedded PC running Angstrom Linux. When the network is unavailable during the boot, it won't become available when I for example connect it to a network afterwards. When I reboot the device (which I'd like to avoid), it works because the network is available from the beginning.

I tried to bring the Eth0 interface up with `ifup eth0`, but it ended with error message: `ifup: can't open '/etc/network/interfaces': No such file or directory`. (Of course, the network is managed by Conman now and the classic folders from other Linux OS are not present. I wonder why they kept `ifup` present in the system...). So I tried to restart the interface with:

```
service network restart
/etc/init.d/network restart
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

None of the commands worked. How do I restart the eth0 interface on the embedded PC running Angstrom OS → recognize Ethernet cable plugged in after boot?

Comment: Can you install ifplugd?

Comment: @eyoung100: I tried. There's already busybox present in the OS, but it doesn't contain ifplugd. I'm currently trying to get a new version, but opkg refuses to download it.

Comment: Well ifplugd is the detection daemon for the network cable, so you need this tool or it's equivalent for your distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in not recognizing when the Ethernet cable is reconnected was caused by a hardware error. I replaced the embedded PC and it worked fine.

But still, sometimes the network becomes unreachable even when other devices in the network can reach it without a problem and this can be fixed by running following command:

```
systemctl restart network.target
```